# MediaPlayer can't turn volume back up

Tags: android, volume

Hello i am working on little android app witch has some sounds. I am trying to make a toggle style button to enable/disable the audio. I tried it this way. The audio plays fine oncreate and when i click the button once it goes off like it's supposed to but it won't come back on

```
boolean volon = true;

player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aud);
player.setLooping(true);    
player.setVolume(100,100);
player.start();

volumebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (volon) {
                player.setVolume(0, 0);
                volumebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.voff);
                volon = false;
            }else {
                player.setVolume(100, 100);
                volumebtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.von);
                volon = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Log cat output:

```
07-21 15:36:36.363  29651-29651/maantje.com.gambleking I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
07-21 15:36:36.441  29651-29651/maantje.com.gambleking I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
07-21 15:36:36.443  29651-29651/maantje.com.gambleking V/MediaPlayer[Native]﹕ MediaPlayer::setVolume(0.000000, 0.000000)
07-21 15:36:37.220  29651-29651/maantje.com.gambleking I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
07-21 15:36:37.275  29651-29651/maantje.com.gambleking I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
07-21 15:36:37.276  29651-29651/maantje.com.gambleking V/MediaPlayer[Native]﹕ MediaPlayer::setVolume(100.000000, 100.000000)
```

The logcat confirms the audio is being toggled from 0 to 100 yet i don't hear any audio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a value between 0.0f and 1.0f

[MediaPlayer.setVolume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume%28float,%20float%29)

Comment: Works like a charm now! But i can't help to find it strange that initially player.setVolume(100, 100); worked but it doesn't work when used again. Ill accept your answer when i can.

Comment: Could be as simple as the MediaPlayer state somehow being corrupted by the first pass of the 100 values.  Hard to say without looking at the MediaPlayer source.

Comment: @marsje Id guess that the first call doesn't do anything, but is defaulted to on.